# Compare similar objects in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, comparison

I need to compare two objects. But it fails.

Code:

```
export class SourceValues {
  ...
  static INDICATOR: ISourceValue = { text: 'Indicator', value: 'Indicator' };
  ...
}
```

somewhere else

```
let a = { text: 'Indicator', value: 'Indicator' } as ISourceValue;
...
if(a === SourceValues.INDICATOR){ // I don't want any change here
//do something
}
```

When I run this, both `a` and `SourceValues.INDICATOR` holds the same value / object. but the comparison fails. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `===` to compare objects in javascript.
In javascript `===` compare memory location as its an object, as both objects have different memory locations it will always be false.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/4743730) to compare two objects properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unline primary types, objects are compared by their references and will not result as equal. Check the link for further reading: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html